# What RSA Encryption Methods should I use to generate the Signature for JWT Authentication?

Tags: .net, docusignapi

I am attempting to build out a request for a JWT Auth Token. I have my header and body base64 encoded, I have generated my public and private keys to use for the final encryption. What method do I use to build out the signature? I have been looking through the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider?view=netframework-4.8 page to see what methods might be available to me, but if someone could confirm which method I should be using, and how I should pass my data into such method, that would be appreciated.

Comment: are you asking about DocuSign, and how to use JWT to authenticate to DocuSign API? If so, ou don't need to generate a signature, you need to first get an access token and then you can make API calls

Comment: Yes, the JWT Authentication page on docusign states that you need to build out the JWT object (including a signature) before you can get an access token, this JWT building process is step 2, and obtaining the token apparently happens in step three once this process is completed

Comment: Why not use an SDK? we have 6 langs

Comment: I am working in .net core and the project has had project breaking issues trying to work with the docusign libraries, this is why I initially had asked if it was possible to use a rest api endpoint. Sorry, I'm just at my wits end at this point

Comment: can you email me at inbar.gazit@docusign.com I'll help you out. You can still use the C# SDK

Comment: So, I want to help you, but not sure I want to answer this question now that I understand what you are trying to do. I think the C# SDK dll dependency issue is easier and the right approach is to use the SDK. Writing your own encryption code (or using some library) is not considered a good security practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use one of our SDKs, as that is the most secure way to go.
If you choose to do it yourself, you need to use SHA256 RSA encryption.
Here is an example -http://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/

However, the above repo is not actively being developed, which may suggest a security risk for you. We highly recommend you find a highly secure library.